# Entity name is different then the table name in Cakephp 3

Tags: php, entity, cakephp-3.0

i have a little problem when i create my models in Cakephp 3, i have to table (pistolets and cuves) associeted with a " hasOne association, the problem is when i creat my Cuves model using ./cake bake i get an Entity called Cufe, i don't know where that name is coming from, and also when i call `$pistolets = $this->Pistolets->find('all')->contain('Cuves');` i also get an object that looks like this :

```
        [id] => 1
        [libelle] => P1
        [volumetrique_id] => 1
        [cuve_id] => 1
        [pompiste_id] => EE324925
        [date_affectation] => Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2016-03-10 00:00:00
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => UTC
            )
        [cufe] => Cake\ORM\Entity Object
            (
                [_properties:protected] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [libelle] => C1
                        [capacite] => 2000
                        [carburant_id] => 1
                    )
```

i checked every piece of code that i wrote and i was enable to find the word `Cufes` in any of it, can anyone please explane how cakephp 3 generates codes ? could it be a bug or it's just my mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bake follows CakePHPs naming conventions, they are english based, and entity names are by convention ment to be the singular variant of the table name.

Using non-english words may leave you with unexpected results when inflection is being applied.

**http://sandbox3.dereuromark.de/sandbox/inflector?string=cuves**

Ideally you should not programm in your local language, but in english, not only does this help future developers and whoever is going too look at your code for whatever reason, it  would solve this issue too.

That being said, one workaround would be to add custom inflections (you would set them in your bootstrap)

```
\Cake\Utility\Inflector::rules('irregular', ['cuve' => 'cuves']);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Inflector > Inflection Configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/inflector.html#inflection-configuration)**

Comment: Thank you very much, it's been 3 days now that i'm googling, i woud've never figure it out by myself, and thank you for the links, i'm very greatful